# How to deploy basic website files on hostgator?

Tags: git, deployment, hosting

This seems like it would be an easy thing to do but I cannot find anywhere that shows me step by step how to do this.

I have a domain name and server on hostgator and I am trying to push my basic website files to my domain name. I have a git repo that has two files; an html and css file.

What are the steps to deploying the files to my domain name?

Any help would be appreciated thank you!

Comment: You just need to download FTP tools like Filezilla and then plesae just upload it to your server. It's simple as that. :)

Answer (score 1):

How to Upload Website Files Using File Manager with HostGator

- Login to cPanel (Can be found in the email from HostGator subject
  line "HostGator.com :: Your Account Info" under Your Control Panel)
- Under Files (or Popular Links at the top near WordPress), click [File 
  Manager](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ofk9g.png)
- In your Finder (on Mac), right click on folder and select: Compress
  ""
- In the cPanel File Manager page from the /home1/ main directory, click Upload from the top toolbar, it will take you to another page, click the Select File button, and choose the compressed zip file folder.
- Once you see it on the page, right click and select "Extract" to unzip the file.
- Then drag and drop the unzipped file into the "public_html" folder.
- You may experience a delay before it appears at your domain name.
  Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

I was able to solve this by following these steps:

1. Create a zip file of your site files
2. Log into your hostgator cpanel
3. Navigate to your file manager
4. Upload your zip file to the main directory
5. Extract your files into the main directory. Once completed refresh to view your folder.
6. Cut your files into the public_html folder and you are done.